# Accessing a Terraform variable from a map?

Tags: terraform, auth0

I'm trying to reach the `aws_partner_event_source` variable that sits within sink{} inside the resource.

```
resource "auth0_log_stream" "aws_logstream" {
  name   = "AWS Eventbridge Auth0 Log Stream"
  type   = "eventbridge"
  status = "active"

  sink {
    aws_account_id = "xxx"
    aws_region     = "eu-west-1"
    aws_partner_event_source = "xxx"
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_bus" "event_bridge_event_bus" {
  event_source_name = auth0_log_stream.aws_logstream.sink[aws_partner_event_source]
}
```

This however, doesn't work. I get:
`A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.`

I also tried:

```
event_source_name = auth0_log_stream.aws_logstream.sink[2]
```

Which throws:

`auth0_log_stream.aws_logstream.sink is list of object with 1 element │  │ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.`

These are the possible solutions I found when looking through Terraform Variable docs, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How about `event_source_name = auth0_log_stream.aws_logstream.sink[0].aws_partner_event_source`?

Comment: Just added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `sink` is a list of objects with one element (as per the error output), the correct syntax is:

```
event_source_name = auth0_log_stream.aws_logstream.sink[0].aws_partner_event_source
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variable using:

```
auth0_log_stream.aws_logstream.sink.aws_partner_event_source
```

as it is not a list to index with `[]`, but an object with named attribute.

Comment: The square bracket notation is used also when resources are created with `for_each`, which is not a list.

Comment: Does not work. "Block type "sink" is represented by a list of objects, so it must be indexed using a numeric key, like .sink[0]"

Answer (score 0):

you can access the attribute by using attribute

`auth0_log_stream.aws_logstream.sink[0].aws_partner_event_source`